# Trying to DBAN 2009 Mac Mini

Tags: usb, startup

I'm trying to DBAN -- or otherwise wipe -- my old 2009 Mac OS X 10.6 Mac mini.  The CD drive on the Mac is broken, so I have been trying to do it with a bootable USB.  No matter what I try, I cannot get the USB drive to show in Startup Manager.

This is what I've got so far:

1. DBAN 2.3 iso downloaded
2. UNetbootin to make the bootable image
3. The Cruzer pen-drive is formatted HFS+ with GUID Partition map -- DiskUtil reports the non-EFI, DBAN partition as bootable.
4. I've tried various key combinations to reset NVRAM,
5. I've follow apple.com advice on how to set legacy insecure behavior on NVRAM

... but still I can only see the Macintosh HD as boot drive. I have tried Command, Shift, Option and Period but nothing happens.

I started with the USB drive formatted FAT32, MBR Partition table and moved on from there.

**Edit:** I originally thought this was a 2011 Mac Mini, I was looking in the wrong place for the year. It turns out that it being from 2009 was **vitally** important,

Comment: If you have another computer then take the drive out and format it on the other machine.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing - made easier as the Mac is being scrapped anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a hard disk drive (HDD), the use of a third party tool is unnecessary. You can boot to [macOS Recovery over the internet](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) and use the Disk Utility application to accomplish this task.

The possible security options available are as follows:

- US Department of Defense (DOD) 5220-22 M standard for securely erasing magnetic media. It erases the information used to access your files and writes over the data 7 times.
- DOE-compliant 3-pass secure erase. It writes two passes fo random data followed by a single pass of known data over the entire disk. It erases the information used to access your files and writes over the data 3 times.
- Write a pass of random data and then a single pass of zeros over the entire disk. It erases the information used to access your files and writes over the data 2 times.

Note: The security options available can very from type of download chosen and the model/year of your Mac.

### USB Flash Drive Method.

See the website [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) for instructions.

You will need to download OS X El Capitan from the Apple website: [How to download OS X El Capitan](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206886). The upgrade can be used with your Snow Leopard OS X 10.6. Although, you ***might*** need to make sure you have first upgraded to OS X 10.6.8. If this case, try downloading the [Mac OS X 10.6.8 Update Combo v1.1](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1399?locale=en_US).

Boot from the USB Flash drive and use the Disk Utility application.

Comment: I've tried that (Sorry, should have said) but no matter how I time pressing and/or releasing Command+R the Mac always boots to the login screen. It's wired ethernet port died a long time ago so it only has internet access by AirPort, I don't know if that matters.

Comment: Have you tried Option+Command+R, then trying to connect wirelessly?

Comment: Yes, no luck with that either: It just doesn't want to boot to Recovery. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try using a flash drive. See updated answer.

Comment: I think it's going to be **"Take off and nuke the site from orbit"** -- looking again it's a 2009 Mac Mini which doesn't feature anywhere. Thanks very much for your suggestions.

Comment: I already knew something was wrong. This [web site](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_mini/specs/mac-mini-core-i5-2.3-mid-2011-specs.html) showed the 2011 Mac mini was shipped with OS X 10.7 and your post showed 10.6.

Comment: Look, you are still in the game. See my updated answer.

Comment: I've gone with the nuclear option: this has taken far too much time already but thanks again for your help.